# Part of Proof of the Uniqueness of the Solution of SDE's

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

[image]
[image]

This is an extract from Oksendal's SDE of the proof of the uniqueness of the solution of a SDE.

I cannot see how the $P[|X_t-\hat{X_t}|=0 \ \ \ \text{for all t} \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,T]]=1$ is derived. Also, I cannot see why is done just for the rationals.

Furthermore, I cannot see why how or why (5.2.11) is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, if $f(t)$ is a continuous function, then the existence of any $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t) > \epsilon$ implies the existence of a rational $s \in [0,1]$ such that $f(s) > \epsilon$. In other words, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the two sets 
$$\{\omega : \exists t \in [0,1] \text{ s.t. } |f(t,\omega)| > 1/n\} = \{\omega : \exists t \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} \text{ s.t. } |f(t,\omega)| > 1/n\}$$
are equal. To see this, call the set on the left $A_n$ and the set on the right $B_n$. Clearly $B_n \subset A_n$. For the converse, let $\omega \in A_n$ and for this $\omega$ let $t$ be such that $f(t,\omega) > 1/n$. Since $(n^{-1},\infty)$ is open, there is an open ball $U$ centred at $t$ such that $f(s,\omega) > 1/n$ for any $s \in U$. Pick a rational $s \in U$. Then $f(s,\omega) > 1/n$, so $\omega \in B_n$.

Since $P(A_n) = P(B_n) = 0$ for all $n$, the claim follows by taking complements and using subadditivity.

Comment: Why was it done just for the rationals in the first place?

Comment: Most likely because the rationals are countable and $\sigma$-algebras are "creatures of countability", as the master probabilist Kai-Lai Chung says. For instance, you might want to prove a certain set $A$ has some property, you might want to write $A = \cup_{\epsilon > 0} A_\epsilon$ for some measurable sets $A_\epsilon$. However, you only know $\cup_{\epsilon > 0, \epsilon \in\mathbb{Q}} A_\epsilon$ is in your $\sigma$-algebra, and this usually suffices. I really recommend you look at an introductory probability textbook before moving onto stochastic calculus.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense. I have already covered the Probability and Measure course at Cambridge which seems to mostly be sufficient for Oksendal's book. Is there measure based probability book you had in mind?

Comment: That's fair, but in my experience it takes more than a single course in measure theory to really "get it" (if that is even possible). Based on your previous questions, the basics of functional analysis, $L^p$ spaces, approximation theorems (like $C^\infty_0$ being dense in $L^2$). Exercises on $\sigma$-algebras (e.g., show that the Borel sigma algebra on $C([0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is the same as the one generated by finite-dimensional sets), etc.

Comment: Here are a few exercises: if $\mu(F) = \nu(F)$ for all closed $F$, then $\mu = \nu$, prove that the same holds if $\int f d\mu = \int f d\nu$ for all bounded, uniformly cont. $f$; prove that if $\eta \in C^\infty$ and $f \in L^1$, then $\eta * f := \int_{-\infty}^\infty \eta(y)f(x-y) dy \in C^\infty$; show that a single measure on a separable metric space is tight; lots of exercises with discrete martingales; do exercises in Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory." Davar Khoshnevisan's "Probability" is *fantastic* as far as detail in arguments goes. Also, master Brownian motion.

Comment: Also just browse Did's posting history and read everything he writes.